# What is the use of backslash in an URL?

Tags: php, apache, url, backslash

I have a front controller in my PHP project. Here is the code;

`.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

`index.php` file

```
<?php
list($url) = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$url = trim(trim($url), '/');

if(!file_exists('pages/'.$url.'.php')
    header('Location: 404.html');

require_once 'inc/head.php';
require_once 'pages/'.$url.'.php';
require_once 'inc/foot.php';
?>
```

I assumed every requested URL must go through index.php file. But if there is a `\` (as %5C) in URL server answer is "Not Found".

Questions;

- Why there is an exception for `\` character? Is there any characters like that?
- What is the reqular use of `\` character to make Apache search for a file? Why not just ignore?
- Where Apache looks and not founds the file?

Note: My system is Windows with Apache 2.2.21 and PHP 5.3.10.
Note2: This is just an example code, so do not offer a better way.

Comment: `\\` is a path separator on Windows. Could that be a cause?

Comment: `.*` must catch everything. So it can't. See the Michel Feldheim's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Comment above said it already:</strike>

On Windows `\` is the path separator
So requesting `'http://localhost/\'`  on a windows system will be caught by the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d`, simply your document root, which is a directory.

You have inverted the condition, d (`!-d`) so apache does not execute the rewrite rule but looks for the default index file, which does not exist, you get a 404

Remove the condition "not a existing directory" or add the index.php to the list of defaults

**EDIT:**

The story I wrote had such a plausible character that I believed it by myself :)
Indeed, this is not even Windows but Apache specific.

Because of a `security leak in CGI` Apache introduced this as a fix many years ago.
Instead of processing the request, it immediately returns a `404 Not Found`, when you pass either `%5C (backslash)` or `%2F (slash)` in the request URL.

I was able to reproduce this on a `Apache 2.2.14`.

If you do not use `CGI` ( e.g. Perl website ) you can safely disable this "security fix":

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On
```

This was introduced in Apache 2.0.46, see [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes), setting this variable didn't work in my `.htaccess`, I had to put it into the `vhost config` and `restart the apache` server.

Comment: index.php is a default file AFAIK. There is a index.php file in document root but results are same. I checked document root from `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. Did you mean a different path or different list of defaults?

Comment: Did you try to remove the -d cond?

Comment: Even tried only with only `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]`, still same.

Comment: Then I was wrong. The reason still might be windows related. I'll try to reproduce this on my xampp

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure what did you Googled to find this, but you did find it, thank you :)